# What should be minimum deployment target set for iphone application while releasing it to App strore?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Hi I am new to the iPhone App development. Currently I released a small application to App store having deployment version 4.3. But some users are not able to download and install the app due to version compatibility. I searched on internet but I didn't get much solution. Now what version should I set while deployment so that every user can use the application?

Answer (score 3):

You should set your minimum deployment version according to API methods you use in your app, i.e. if you use methods from iOS 5 SDK and don't make your app backwards compatible (with support for older versions of iOS), you should set min deployment version to iOS 5. How would you care about users who don't have newer iOS installed is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment target is the minimum version of iOS that is going to be supported by the application. It means iTunes store will allow the users downloading this application having same or higher iOS version on their devices.

To achieve it developer should take care while using the APIs. The API version should not be higher than deployment target iOS version. If you need to use higher API, you should use

[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion to check the target device version.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the Deployment target to that of the lowest OS device upon which you have actually tested that version of your app.  Many developers keep or borrow an old non-upgraded iOS device just for that purpose. Otherwise your customers become your alpha testers.

Answer (score 0):

go for 3.0 if your code supports that,
maybe that code changes are needed.